# Read uwsgi_param from Bottle

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, bottle

I have a python3 application running under a nginx/uwsgi application. It's a multi-environment app, so I decided to create diferent virtualhosts for each environment. On each virtualhost I define the environment:

```
uwsgi_param APPLICATION_ENV dev;
```

But I cannot read from Bottle, I'm trying:

```
request.environ['APPLICATION_ENV']
```

or

```
request.environ.get('APPLICATION_ENV')
```

I'm trying other solutions but none of them works, what am I doing wrong??

Comment: I need to specify, I want to do it before my app.run, as it is a multi database app and I have to connect to database at this point (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

It is important to know that uwsgi_params will be loaded after a request is done, so this is why each time i execute request.environ I don't get the uwsgi value. If I move this line to an @app.route, it works.

So, in order to fix this, I added a uswgi variable into my uwsgi_app.ini file:

```
env = APPLICATION_ENV=dev
```

Then in your python code, before your app.run(), you can get the variable APPLICATION_ENV as follows:

```
import os
application_env = os.getenv('APPLICATION_ENV', socket.gethostname())
```

Where socket.gethostname() is the default value if APPLICATION_ENV is not found.